# Build ASM code using libtool and autoconf

Tags: c++, c, assembly, automake, libtool

I am using `libtool` and `automake` to build our project. Project has CPP and ASM code.
CPP code is built properly and `.o` files are created.

To build ASM code below given instructions are given in config

`AM_PROG_AS`, `CCASFLAGS`

ASM code seems to be not building. In compilation summery I see that ASM code with .s extension is built but object file are missing. When I run below command separately(Which I have taken from the verbose of compilation) it runs but not generating the object file.

`libtool: compile:  gcc -S -DARCH_X86_64=1 -g -O2 -c file.s  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/file.o`

What could be the reason ?? Any additional configuration is required.

Is there any option where I can force libtool to use yasm for ASM code building??

Comment: Why the [tag:c] tag if you're writing C++?

Answer (score 0):

`-S` option instructs gcc to generate an assembly file, not assemble. It only makes sense for C files, if you want to examine generated assembly code. Remove that. Next time consult the [manual for the meaning of the options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-S-80).

Comment: As you mentioned -S flag is used to generate .s files. This is not use full for me.

Is it possible to force libtool to choose yasm assembler to assemble the .s files??

Comment: Drop the `-S` and then gcc will assemble. Presumably yeah you can use yasm, but then make sure your files are compatible.